# Add chronological number to a column if empty

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence

I have a dataframe with a column called 's_nummer'. This column is sometimes NA and in that case, I would like to add a number myself that can range from 700001 to 800000. So in this case, row numbers 3 and 4 do not contain a value in the s_nummer column and I would like to add the values 700001 to row 3 and 700002 to row 4.

dput:

```
structure(list(s_nummer = c(599999, 599999, NA, NA), eerste_voornaam = c("Debbie", 
"Debbie", "Debbie", "Debbie"), tussenvoegsel = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA), geslachtsnaam = c("Oomen", "Oomen", "Oomen", "Oomen")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Hope you can help!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `which` with `is.na` to get the lines with `NA` in *x$s_nummer* and overwrite them with 700000 + `seq_along`.

```
i <- which(is.na(x$s_nummer))
x$s_nummer[i] <- 700000 + seq_along(i)
#  s_nummer eerste_voornaam tussenvoegsel geslachtsnaam
#1   599999          Debbie            NA         Oomen
#2   599999          Debbie            NA         Oomen
#3   700001          Debbie            NA         Oomen
#4   700002          Debbie            NA         Oomen
```